# Filtering SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, where-clause

I am trying to figure out what to put in the `WHERE` clause that will return the `m.sender` id, a count of `m.receiver` id's that are **NOT** in the `m.sender`'s department, and the department name that `m.sender` is in.
For example, if the `m.sender` id is in 'Sales', the count of `m.receiver` ids will be from all departments except 'Sales'.
I am trying to find a list of `m.sender` ids that have the highest out of department communication.
(Using Google BigQuery)

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.sender, COUNT(DISTINCT m.receiver) AS messages_received, e.department
FROM collaboration.messages as m
JOIN collaboration.employees as e
ON m.sender = e.id
WHERE ?
GROUP BY m.sender, e.department
ORDER BY messages_received DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

| messages | messages sent and received |
| --- | --- |
| sender | represents the employee id of the employee sending the message. |
| receiver | represents the employee id of the employee receiving the message. |

| employees | information on each employee |
| --- | --- |
| id | represents the employee id of the employee |
| department | is the department within the company. |

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, your GROUP BY eliminates all duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly this could be what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.sender, COUNT(DISTINCT m.receiver) AS messages_received, e.department
FROM collaboration.messages as m
JOIN collaboration.employees as e
ON m.sender = e.id

LEFT JOIN collaboration.employees as receiver_dep
ON m.receiver = receiver_dep.id 

WHERE receiver_dep.department <> e.department

GROUP BY m.sender, e.department
ORDER BY messages_received DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

You need an extra join to obtain the receiver's department and check if it is different from the sender's.